# how to get the data from database

Tags: html

actually i created a form and the inputs have been stored into the database succesfully.. then i retreived those inputs in the browser in table format ..now i added another column(delete) in browser table where i have data in that column is delete link which moves to delete.php page...now wat i need to code in display.php page to delete the specified row ?? i tried but i am not sure about that how to make that specific row .
        this is my browser display.php page

```
    ?>
      <table border="2">
    <th>
    <tr>
          <th>SNO</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>email</th>
          <th>gender</th>
          <th>language</th>
          <th>country</th>
          <th>interest</th>
          <th>edit</th>
          <th>delete</th>
    </tr>
    </th>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>' .$row['SNO'] .'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['gender'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['language'] .'</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $row['country'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $row['interest'] .'</td>';
             echo '<td>' .'<a href="http://192.168.1.37/TRAINING/krishnaswamy/html/edit.php">edit</a>'  .'</td>';
             echo '<td>' .'<a href="http://192.168.1.37/TRAINING/krishnaswamy/html/delete.php">delete</a>'.'</td>';
             echo '</tr>';

    }
    } 
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
This is my code were is show the table . i made the links to move to edit.php and delete.php page respectively...so wat i need to do as acode in that respective pages
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add POST variables in the delete.php URL so:

```
echo '<td>' .'<a href="http://192.168.1.37/TRAINING/krishnaswamy/html/delete.php?idX="'.$row['uniqueID'].'">delete</a>'.'</td>';
```

Then on the delete.php page you can retrieve it with:

```
$_POST["idX"];
```

Comment: idx is a id right?? i used sno so i need to replace it by sno then .$row['uniqueID'] ..may i know the use of that row['uniqueid;]....

Comment: I wasn't sure what sno was used for but if that is unique to all entries you will replace 'uniqueID' with 'sno'.

Comment: idx is just a variable right...we can use use anything there no issue in that right. after getting $_POST["idx"] i nee to drop statement or else anyother way ?? tell me the code too

Comment: not working ji the above suggested code.. this is delete.php code<?php
$res=$_POST["id"];
$sql=delete from form where SNO='$res';
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
{
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else 
{
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>here the link   echo '<td>' .'<a href="http://192.168.1.37/TRAINING/krishnaswamy/html/delete.php?id="'.$row['SNO'].'">delete</a>'.'</td>';

Comment: First echo the POST['id'] and make sure you are retrieving it correctly. 
Second the $sql statement should be in " "

Comment: ya its not retreiving the value

Comment: Make sure it is formatted like /delete.php?idX= I did a few edits before.
Also just use idX just in case 'id' is a reserved word.

Comment: is there anyother answers can i expect else i need to move on my own thoughts

Comment: Post your code and I will see if there is anything I can do.